# sqlite3 queries not being executed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am working on something using SQLite3 and I cant exactly figure out why I am getting an error. I have looked at other SO post and no one can actually quite put a finger on that error and I have tried a number of things. the code is failing on this line `(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &itemDB)==SQLITE_OK)`. 
I have tried:

- commenting that line and saying `sqlite3_open(dbPath, &itemDB)`, when i do that my code excecutes but nothing in the folder
- Error from the NSLog was "unable to open database file" so i created the datbase and placed it in the path myself to see if that would help but no difference
- Verified the path by using breakpoints, path is correct but the db is just never created.

  ```
       -(void)openDatabase
      {
              NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
              NSString *docPath=[path objectAtIndex:0];

              // dbPathString=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"items.db"];
              dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"items.sqlite"];
              char *error;
              NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
              if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {
                  const char *dbPath=[dbPathString UTF8String];
                  //Create DB
                  if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &items)==SQLITE_OK)

                      //  sqlite3_open(dbPath, &items);

         {
      const char *sql_stmt= " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST PERSON (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,PRICE INTEGER)";
      sqlite3_exec(items, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
      sqlite3_close(items);
      NSLog(@"Db Created");
         }
                  NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(items));
              }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write to the *documentation* directory, not the *document* directory.
Replace `NSDocumentationDirectory` with `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Comment: whoa...just whoa. Never saw that, Problem was when i type "NSD" i just tab cause intellisence comes up and just completes it. So simple

Answer (score -1):

Try this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application)

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO) {
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
            status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
    else {
        status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
    }
}
```

Comment: How is a blob of code that does something *different* supposed to be an answer?

Answer (score -1):

This will help u

```
#import<sqlite3.h>

    -(BOOL)createTable
    {
        NSArray *yourArray=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath=[yourArray objectAtIndex:0];

    filePath =[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdatabase.sqlite"];

    NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL success = NO;
    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) 
    {
        success =YES;
    }
    if (!success) 
    {
        NSString *path2=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdatabase.sqlite"];
        success =[manager copyItemAtPath:path2 toPath:filePath error:nil];
    }
    createStmt = nil;
    NSString *tableName=@"SecondTable";
    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (createStmt == nil) {

            NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,PRICE INTEGER)];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &createStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                return NO;
            }
            sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: This is neither valid Objective-C code nor valid SQL code.